# DNS - Non FQDN fails to resolve on Mobile Devices

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

We have a domain network, with the domain mycompany.local as an example.

DNS server is running on Server 2008 R2.

We have a server:

Server1.mycompany.local which has IP: 10.1.1.1

On any Windows machine on the network, I can ping either server1 or server1.mycompany.local and it resolves and pings the correct IP of 10.1.1.1

Seemingly on any Windows Mobile 6.5 or Android device connected to the network via WiFi, if I ping server1 I get no response. 
If I ping server1.mycompany.local, it resolves with the correct IP and can ping no problem.

On the DNS server, there is a forward lookup zone for mycompany.local and server1 has a record with ip 10.1.1.1

I'm assuming it's because the devices aren't joined to the domain.
What is the solution to this?

Comment: Make sure dhcp passes domain-name to clients. Android I heard has some bugs in that area.

Comment: And how is that setup?

Domain server is not the DHCP server.

Android is not the main issue, as we simply used that to demonstrate the issue exists on both systems.

Windows Mobile is used for some handheld computers and so this is the main problem.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The dhcp server has to pass the domain search list to the clients using dhcp options. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572752%28v=office.13%29.aspx

Comment: I added the record to the DHCP server, and it's made no difference.
Still fails to resolve on Android and Windows Mobile device.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your DNS Search suffix on your DHCP server. You may be running into an issue where some clients do not like how Microsoft DHCP formats the information, [this link covers how to work around that problem](http://www.mattzuba.com/2011/03/windows-2008-rc2-dhcp-server-option-119/).